Under what conditions is the matrix norm of $||(R + A^T P A)^{-1}B^T P||$ finite for all positive semi-definite matrices $P$?
Assume $R$ is a positive definite matrix, $A$ and $B$ are square matrices, and $P$ is a positive semi-definite matrix. I would like to know the conditions under which  $\sup_{P \geq 0} \|(R + A^T P A)^{-1} B^T P\| < \infty$
In the one-dimensional case, having A invertible is a sufficient condition for the norm to be finite. Does this insight help to identify conditions for the general case?
Thank you for your help and insights!
